# Counting most common names in an user inputted list?

Tags: python-3.x

So my problem is like this, from a list that is made by a user. The number of names is also chosen by them. It looks something like this. (Apologies for the code).

```
from collections import Counter
inputcount = int(input("Enter number of players."))
count = 1
list_of_integers = []
playerno = 1
while count <= inputcount:
    appendinput = str(input("Enter name of player no %s: "%(playerno)))
    list_of_integers.append(appendinput)
    playerno += 1
    count += 1
    cnt = Counter(list_of_integers)

print(cnt.most_common())
```

In the output it shows the all input and their count, but I need it to only show the most recurring one and it's count. I have to use a function to find the most common element.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).  You're looking for `cnt.most_common(1)`

Comment: That works great thanks. But how do I then print it in output to print the most common name, and the count in the output?